# Remove images from document but not in this class

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I would like to get rid of images in iframe except for the images found in some class. I have inserted some variables:

```
var class = '.class';
var index = '5';


$('#iframe').contents().find('* img').not(class + ':eq('+ index +')' + ' img').remove();
```

As far as I understand this should remove everything except the images in class. It's not working, all the images are being removed. The not selector isn't effective it seems. What am I doing wrong? What else can I try?

Comment: where is the `class` present? is it in the element or in its parent. and what about the `index`?

Comment: @Arun P Johny It shouldn't matter where it is, Im targeting the document (*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use a filter, easier to read and control.

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('img').parent().filter(function() {
    return !($(this).hasClass('class') && $(this).index() == 5);
}).remove();
```

As a sidenote, `class` is a reserved keyword, and not a good name for a variable.

Comment: The variable is just an example to simplify things

Comment: @Youss - You're welcome. A filter is usually easier to read, and you can exclude / include almost anything in the boolean return statement.

Comment: @Youss - Depends, from the question it looks like you're trying to remove the parent(), as that is the element you're specifically targeting, but that's up to you ?